# Move object relative to the direction it's facing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to move an object upwards relative to the direction it's facing. I have a CubeGeometry with a certain height, and I want to put an object at the top of it, and rotate with the cube. I cannot just add the new object to the cube because I need to be able to access the rotation of this object (which will be rotated later) and the parent object. For example, if you were facing up, "up" would be sideways. I have tried to get the direction something is facing with .getWorldDirection() and rotating it using .applyAxisAngle(), but this does not work for some reason. My code right now:

```
tmpObj.position.set(cube.position.x, cube.position.y, cube.position.z); // put at the position of the cube
var gwd = cube.getWorldDirection().applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), Math.PI*-0.5); // if you don't do the applyAxisAngle, it will be facing the wrong direction
gwd.multiplyScalar(2.5); // the height of the cube
tmpObj.position.add(gwd);
```

This makes the cube (`tmpObj`) go the wrong way when `cube` is rotated.

For reference, there is another `tmpObj` and `cube` (named differently) that will then point at each other in order to detect what side of each other they are on.

Comment: Are you trying to get the object's up-vector? In local or world coordinates?

Comment: @TheJim01 I'm new to three.js, can you explain the difference?

Comment: It's all about frame of reference. Consider observing a person laying on their side. "up" to you is not "up" to them _locally_, even though your "up" matches the _global_ "up". In 3D graphics "up" is a normalized vector which indicates what is "up" with respect to the object. In three.js, most objects start with "up" being `(0, 1, 0)`. If you rotate an object 90° about the Z-axis, "up" is still `(0, 1, 0)` _locally_ (to the object), but becomes `(1, 0, 0)` _globally_. Every three.js 3D object has a _local_ [`up`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.up) property.

Comment: @TheJim01 Looking for global, thanks for the good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In three.js, an object is considered to be facing in the direction of its local, positive Z-axis. (The exception is a camera, which faces its local, negative Z-axis.)

By default, the local, positive Y-axis is "up" in the object's local coordinate system.

You can translate an object in the direction of its local, positive Y-axis like so:

```
object.translateY( distance );
```

three.js r.90

Comment: Thank you, but I’m looking for the global up property. See my response to the comment on the question.